# XML Serialization by Type Attribute

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, soap

I have such a situation:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlType]
public class MyMessage
{
    [XmlElement]
    public object data;
}
[Serializable]
[XmlType(Namespace = "http://comp.com/types")]
public class SomeClass
{
    [XmlElement]
    public string SomeString { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public int SomeInt { get; set; }
}
[Serializable]
[XmlType(Namespace = "http://comp.com/types")]
public class OtherClass
{
    [XmlElement]
    public string OtherString { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public int OtherInt { get; set; }
}
```

I need get xml like this:

```
<data xsi:type="ns1:SomeClass" xmlns:ns1="http://comp.com/types">
    <SomeString>someValue</SomeString>
    <SomeInt>10</SomeInt>
</data>
```

and:

```
<data xsi:type="ns1:OtherClass" xmlns:ns1="http://comp.com/types">
    <OtherString>someValue</OtherString>
    <OtherInt>10</OtherInt>
</data>
```

I try add to `data` field attribute:

```
[XmlElement("data", typeof(SomeClass), Namespace = "http://comp.com/types")]
```

It's almost work, but xml attribute `type` is missing. And if I add `XmlElement` for second class `OtherClass`, I getting error:

> The top XML element 'data' from namespace 'http://comp.com/types' references distinct types ObjectModel.SomeClass and ObjectModel.OtherClass. Use XML attributes to specify another XML name or namespace for the element or types.
>   Is it possible to solve this problem? This code use in SOAP service.

Comment: Standard Xml has only one root tag.  You are trying to put two data tags at the root.

Comment: Of course, but I don't trying to put two data tags at the root. I want to put `SomeClass` or `OtherClass` not both.

Comment: Your model is wrong, `data` is your root, and`SomeClass` *is a* `data`There isn't a `MyMessage` involved. Unfortunately, you can get close with [something like this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TsvMjR), but I don't think serializer is going to allow you to have the sub-classes in a different namespace.

Comment: I don't understend your sentence `Your model is wrong`, may be this because I cut this sample from wcf service project. Your solve helped me on this time, but I have to do more tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
    [Serializable]
    [XmlType]
    public class MyMessage
    {
        [XmlElement]
        public List<BaseClass> data;
    }
    [XmlInclude(typeof(SomeClass))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(OtherClass))]

    [Serializable]
    public class BaseClass
    {
    }
    [Serializable]
    [XmlType(Namespace = "http://comp.com/types")]
    public class SomeClass : BaseClass
    {
        [XmlElement]
        public string SomeString { get; set; }

        [XmlElement]
        public int SomeInt { get; set; }
    }
    [Serializable]
    [XmlType(Namespace = "http://comp.com/types")]
    public class OtherClass : BaseClass
    {
        [XmlElement]
        public string OtherString { get; set; }

        [XmlElement]
        public int OtherInt { get; set; }
    }
```